# Randomize Picture with relative text javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to display a random picture with a relative text everytime I load the page. So in order to have Image1 with text1, Image2 with text2 ....

Here is my code :

html :

```
   <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="random-picture.js"></script>
    
    <div class="
              content-with-two-section-2 content-1
              padding-top-8 grey-background
              
            ">
          <div class="hero-content-with-image">
            <img id="randomImages" alt="hero-image">
          </div>
    
          <div class="">
            <div id="" class="section-text-1">
                <h1>RANDOM 1
                  <p>random1</p>
            </div>
           </div>
    <div class="">
            <div id="" class="section-text-2">
                <h1>RANDOM 2
                  <p>random2</p>
            </div>
           </div>
    <div class="">
            <div id="" class="section-text-3">
                <h1>RANDOM 3
                  <p>random3</p>
            </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

I put all classes as display:none; on my css file :

```
.section-text-1, .section-text-2, .section-text-3 {
  display: none; 
}
```

And this is my js file :

```
var image = new Array();
image[0] = "image1.png";
image[1] = "image2.png";
image[2] = "image3.png";
var size = image.length
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())

jQuery('#randomImages').attr('src', image[x]);
```

Thanks a lot for your help !!!!

Comment: Have you tried to do an object with 3 properties : srcImage, title and text ? This way, you will be able to have the title and text related to the image.

Comment: I've just updated my answer adding @archelite alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows:

Enumerating class names is not necessary (you can use '.section-text' alone, because after querying you will get an array with indexes corresponding to the elements order in DOM).

```js
const sources = [
  'image1.png',
  'image2.png',
  'image3.png'
];

const img = document.getElementById('randomImages');
const sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section-text');

const index = Math.floor(sources.length * Math.random());

img.alt = sources[index];
img.src = sources[index];

sections[index].style.display = 'block';
```

```css
.section-text {
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="content-with-two-section-2 content-1 padding-top-8 grey-background">
  <div class="hero-content-with-image">
    <img id="randomImages">
  </div>
    
  <div>
    <div class="section-text">
      <h1>RANDOM 1</h1>
      <p>random1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="section-text">
      <h1>RANDOM 2</h1>
      <p>random2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="section-text">
      <h1>RANDOM 3</h1>
      <p>random3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As an alternative (suggested in comments):

```js
const sources = [
  {
    src: 'image1.png',
    title: 'Image 1',
    text: 'This is text 1'
  },
  {
    src: 'image2.png',
    title: 'Image 2',
    text: 'This is text 2'
  },
  {
    src: 'image3.png',
    title: 'Image 3',
    text: 'This is text 3'
  }
];

const image = document.getElementById('image');
const title = document.getElementById('title');
const text = document.getElementById('text');

const index = Math.floor(sources.length * Math.random());

const source = sources[index];

image.alt = source.src;
image.src = source.src;

title.innerText = source.title;

text.innerText = source.text;
```

```html
<div class="content-with-two-section-2 content-1 padding-top-8 grey-background">
  <div class="hero-content-with-image">
    <img id="image">
  </div>
    
  <div>
    <div class="section-text">
      <h1 id="title"></h1>
      <p id="text"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first version is more suitable with my code , as I have large texts and I don't want to overload my javascript file. Thanks for you help !

Comment: @Adzidue glad to read it worked. Please remember to mark your question as answered if you think you got the answer that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of shuffling algorithm to output random pictures.

```js
function randomPic(arr){
    const arrLength = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
      const indexOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrLength);
      const indexTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrLength);

      
      const tempValue = arr[indexOne];
      arr[indexOne] = arr[indexTwo];
      arr[indexTwo] = tempValue
    }
    
    return arr
  }
  
  
  const sources = [
    {
      src: 'https://image1.png',
      title: 'Title 1',
      text: 'This is text 1'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://image2.png',
      title: 'Title 2',
      text: 'This is text 2'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://image3.png',
      title: 'Title 3',
      text: 'This is text 3'
    }
  ];
  
  console.log(randomPic(sources))
```